# android webview displaying blank page

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-emulator, webview

I have an android application that I am developing using the emulator running on android 2.3.3 with an embedded WebView in a framelayout nested in a linearlayout (vertical). No matter what code I use it never actually does anything. I have Permissions on the android application set to INTERNET. 
Even when trying to load just the HTML code. I get a blank white page, no errors no nothing. Nothing in logcat as well.

```
WebView wview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
wview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

I have tried all three of these to attempt to load anything into the webview:

```
wview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
wview.loadData("<HTML><BODY><H3>Test</H3></BODY></HTML>","text/html","utf-8");
wview.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, "<HTML><BODY><H3>Test</H3></BODY></HTML>","text/html","utf-8",null);
```

All three give me the same results. Nothing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 81):

```
WebSettings settings = wbView.getSettings();
settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

Comment: That was the issue for me. The webview was able to display some web pages, but had a blank screen for some other pages. Adding this solved my problem, thanks!

Comment: I had to use both this and `wbView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`

Comment: save my time...Thank you.

Comment: Made my day ! Thank you !

Comment: Thank you !! Was trying for hours to fix this

Comment: can anyone explains why?

Comment: Thank you so much! This issue could kill me in deadline. Wow!

Answer (score 14):

It might be a bit too late, but I wanted to share my experience with you, because I had the same problem and spent a lot of time on it.

Put your `WebView` in **`RelativeLayout`** and not in **`FrameLayout`**.

What I have tested: My `WebView`'s `onPageFinished()` was called every time, but on the screen I got blank page.

From `chrome://inspect` `WebView` debugger I was able to "ping" my `WebView` by pressing `inspect` button, and after that `WebView` was refreshing immediately.

My thoughts - `WebView` isn't rendered correctly in `FrameLayout`, and `RelativeLayout` fixes the issue (even `invalidate()` and `requestLayout()` calls didn't help).

Comment: Depending on your layout, you also may have to make sure you're setting `android:layout_height="match_parent"` (instead of `wrap_content`), as the webApp might just have zero height at first

Comment: I have the same problem and it is already in relativeLayout ... I even set `settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);` and I still get a white page on a certain link. The link is even https.

Answer (score 12):

I think if you edit some of your code then it will be ok.Look how i do it in my case below.Try for you in this way..
**For displaying a web page**

```
final WebView wbView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebView);

WebSettings settings = wbView.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
wbView.loadUrl("https://play.google.com/store/apps");
wbView.clearView();
wbView.measure(100, 100);
settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
```

**For showing HTML:**
See this tutorial..

- [android-tutorial-html-file-in-webview](http://www.monocube.com/2011/02/08/android-tutorial-html-file-in-webview/)

Answer (score 10):

instead of passing null, you should pass an empty `String` to it. ex: `""`
So you should call it like this:
`wview.loadDataWithBaseURL("", "<HTML><BODY><H3>Test</H3></BODY></HTML>","text/html","utf-8","");`

Comment: This actually resolved a blank issue when replacing this overload: .LoadData(html, mime, encoding).

Answer (score 6):

In my case, it was due to the fact that my webview was attempting to load a page using HTTPS where the certificate was untrusted.

You can check if this is the case in your code using the following snippet:

```
@Override
public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
    handler.proceed();
}
```

*Java*

```
override fun onReceivedSslError(view: WebView?, handler: SslErrorHandler?, error: SslError?) {
    handler?.proceed()
}
```

*Kotlin*

Then, if it is the case, quickly remove the snippet and refer to [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl#CommonProblems) to diagnose the problem further and potentially add the certificate to your keystore.

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction. Annoyingly the `WebView` component does not make use of certificates added to the system key store. I had to instead include the CA cert in the project itself and use a Network Security Config to trust the self-signed cert during debugging.

Comment: Thank you very much, it was my problem of untrusted certif

Answer (score 5):

If it still Doesn't work then please make sure that you have added **"http://"** or **"https://"** before the web address.

Answer (score 4):

I gave +1 because these were both valid assistance to getting the webview to working properly, but it was not the solution to my issue.

What I didn't realize is I had a wrap_content on the include of my webview layout and this caused it to have a height of 0px. By setting this to fill_parent I resolved the issue. (Webview with white background and app with white background you cant really tell its not full height when it shows up as full height in the layout designer.)

Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 4):

`clearView` is deprecated.

Use:

```
webView.loadUrl("about:blank")
```

Answer (score 3):

change wrap_content to fill_parent in your webview layout. it worked for me

Answer (score 2):

use ip address instead of web url then override webclient using following ssl error handling method

```
@Override
public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
    handler.proceed(); // Ignore SSL certificate errors
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just use loadDataWithBaseURL

```
        loadDataWithBaseURL(null,"html content" , "text/html" , "utf-8",null)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code, this will be helpful:

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("www.example.com")) {
            // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load the page
            return false;
        }
        // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch another Activity that handles URLs
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think What you need is WebViewClient. After setting webviewclient call webview.loadUrl(_url);
Somethin like this ....

```
private void loadUrlInWebView(String _URL){
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webviewer);     

    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    myWebView.loadUrl(_URL);
}

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {         

            view.loadUrl(url);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: don't do this. simply returning false from shouldOverrideUrlLoading is enough, no need to call view.loadUrl method

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the **RAM** for your emulated device. That solved the problem for me.

I found this out by looking at the logcat messages in Android Monitor (Android Studio). The messages below gave me the idea about what was wrong to increasing **RAM** :

```
W/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 6635532 byte allocation with 1170528 free bytes and 1143KB until OOM"

W/JavaBrowserViewRendererHelper: Error allocating bitmap

E/chromium: [ERROR:java_browser_view_renderer_helper.cc(132)] Error unlocking java bitmap pixels.
```

Answer (score 0):

My webview was displaying a **white blank square on top of it**, sometimes totally blank. This only occurred when it was loading certain data.

Changing it to a **RelativeLayout**, and setting layout_height to **match_parent** worked for me.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android=...
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        .....

    </RelativeLayout>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/ll_title"
        android:background="@color/colorYellow" />


    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pb_spinning"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was trying to load an html file. The solution came to be:

```
val webClient = object : WebViewClient() {
    override fun onPageCommitVisible(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
        super.onPageCommitVisible(view, myUrl)
        binding.newsWebView.stopLoading()
    }
}

binding.newsWebView.webViewClient = webClient

binding.newsWebView.loadUrl(myUrl)
```

After the html file has been loaded, it loaded about:blank and the screen was going blank.