# Having a blank/white screen on Android WebView

Tags: android

I tried to view my website in the app, but I get a white or blank screen. What can solve this problem? I tried methods from similar questions but nothing helped. What should I do? Pleasa help me.

This is my MainActivity.xml code

```
package com.promil_app.kspromilplock;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wbView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.m.kspromilplock.pl");
    }
}
```

and manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.KSPromilPłock"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [android webview displaying blank page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14300664/android-webview-displaying-blank-page)

Answer (score 0):

If yout want yout webview support http
you can add

`android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"` to AndroidManifest.xml。

app/src/main/res/network_security_config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" />
</network-security-config>
```

use this url "http://www.m.kspromilplock.pl"

```
webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webView.loadUrl("http://www.m.kspromilplock.pl");
```

You can using http instead